# Is the metric space of a family of non-empty subsets of a bounded metric space compact when the latter space is compact?

Tags: analysis

The title's statement with the metric $$\rho=max(sup(d(x;F),sup(d(y;E)))$$ for the subset space of which E and F are members, x in E, y in F, may lack one more predicate: the subsets are closed.  Is it necessary that the subsets be closed?  If yes, then please suggest why.
Note: A hint for the proof of the statement including the closed predicate can be found in Gamelin & Green's Topology. It is too lengthy to be copied here.  I state the question in stand alone form for readers who do not have access to G&G's fine little Dover text.  I have not found in that hint where the closed property is used.

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained. You need to define the particular statements, spaces, metrics, etc. used in this problem for those who don't have this particular book at hand.

Comment: I believe my question now stands alone, apart from the G&G text and can be answered.

Comment: If $E$ is not closed then $E\ne\overline E$ although $\rho(E,\overline E)=0$. I.e., on the space of all (not necessarily closed) nonempty sets, $\rho$ is a pseudometric rather than a metric. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: I believe (without having a proof) that, if $X$ is a compact metric space, then the space of **all** nonempty closed subsets of $X$ is compact, but that isn't what you said. Apparently you want to prove that **"a family"**, any old family, of nonempty closed subsets of $X$ is compact, and that is not believable. If $Y$ is a non-compact subset of $X$, then the family $\{\{y\}:y\in Y\}$ of all one-element subsets of $Y$ will not be compact either.

Comment: By the way your question is not self-contained. It refers to the title, which is not part of the question.

Comment: My question is now self-contained.  The metric of the sub-space has been supplied.

Comment: To bot: My question is now self-contained.  I have supplied the metric of the sub-space.     What is important, I believe, is the calculation of the $\rho$ metric to show the convergence of the chosen sub-sequence to the selected convergence set.  This seems true whether the family of sub-sets is closed or not and also whether the convergence set is closed or not.  $\rho$ -> 0.  I see no use of the closed property in the proof of sequential compactness.  That is the point of my question yet unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not looking at closed subsets then you do *not* have a metric space!  Call the original metric space $(X,d)$. Using the metric $\rho$ in your question, a subset $A$ of $X$ and its closure $\overline{A}$ in $X$ have distance $0$ from each other.  Think about the distance between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ in the metric space $\mathbf R$ (or in a bounded subset of $\mathbf R$ that contains those two intervals). Or think about the distance between the open unit disc and closed unit disc in $\mathbf R^2$ (or in a bounded subset of $\mathbf R^2$ containing those discs).

Since $\rho(A,\overline{A}) = 0$, you need $A = \overline{A}$ for the subsets $A$ that you use.  That is why people work with closed subsets when using the metric $\rho$. See Remark 2.4 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/contraction2.pdf), and for the compactness of the set of nonempty compact subsets of $(X,d)$ when $(X,d)$ is compact, see Theorem 2.24 there.

Comment: @goedelite: To complement this answer, a useful reference, with many proofs given in great detail, for the metric space of nonempty compact subsets of a given metric space is Section 17.6 (pages 121−124) and Exercises 17.13−17.16 (page 135) of [**Point Sets**](https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/402488) by Eduard Čech (1969).

Comment: Yes!   The need for closed sets is not in the proof I have been focusing on, but in the idea of a metric itself - which I had neglected.  If the distance between (0,1) and [0,1] were allowed to be 0, the definition of a metric would be complicated.   Your further references are appreciated!